# Customizing $PATH on Windows OS using .bashrc and Git Bash Terminal

Tags: python, node.js, bash, git-bash

I was trying to follow this tutorial, essentially not actually for Node.js but for Python, because I cannot get Git Bash to find Python, even though python is installed. In fact it wont even find python within the python install directory, when the exe is right there.

Anyway, I tried to follow this tutorial for customizing the $PATH [link](https://medium.com/@pyaephyokyaw_97225/customizing-path-on-windows-os-using-bashrc-and-git-bash-terminal-6832fab9422c)

regarding this part: to set node $PATH, open .bashrc file you created under user home directory.

Do you actually open it, because I'm sure all the instructions after that point refer to commands within gitbash, I don't see the opened file being used at all?

So i used $ env|grep PATH to list all the paths and the PATH to the jupyter-lab executable is right there in the list! still doesn't work. I suppose this will be some syntax issue.

Comment: It depends on your interpretation of the wort _to open_, which may be different from that the author of the article means. To 'open' means that you use a text editor to edit the file.  I suggest that you study the chapter _INVOCATION_ of the bash man page to understand the role of .bashrc, because after this it will be obvious to you what steps to follow.

Comment: The point 5 "Type **PATH=$PATH:**…" is for an editor in which you open `~/.bashrc`. Edit, save, restart open terminals.

Comment: so where is this documentation anyway? I assume you mean bash main page? There is a lot of documentation on what seem like random websites and very little definitely from the source.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Invoking-Bash.html#Invoking-Bash , https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash